# run a code for all rows of table jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using this code to hide the element in sixth column of a table on a condition (I mean if text of span fourth column of table is "0").

But this code just works for first row of table.
How can i do this function for all rows of target table  ?

```
if ($('#table  tr  td:eq(4) > span').text() == "0") {
            $('#table  tr  td:eq(6) > .PrintReport').hide();
        }
```

Comment: all td have PrintReport class?

Comment: can you give us your issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: @Vivek Yes all of them has this class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you could post the full HTML structure of `tr` then you'd get more optimized solutions.  Looking at your existing code you could do something like this:

```
$('#table tr').each(function() {
  var text = $('td:eq(4) > span', this).text();

  $('td:eq(6) > .PrintReport', this).toggle(text != '0');
});
```

Notice that inside the loop I'm using `this` as the context in the selectors.

**EDIT:** Explaining some of the above code -

```
  //This runs the selector in the context of 'this' (the table row)
  //It is functionally equivalent to $(this).find('td:eq(6) > .PrintReport')
  $('td:eq(6) > .PrintReport', this)

  //This will .show() it if the expression evaluates to true
  //and hide if false
  .toggle(text != '0')
```

Comment: I like your implementation :-) +1

Comment: Thanks, Would you please describe this line 
  $('td:eq(6) > .PrintReport', this).toggle(text != '0');
?

Comment: @shaahin Sure, check the edit for an explanation.  @Raja excellent ;p

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#table tr').each(function() {  
     var text = $('td:eq(4) > span', this).text();   
     if(text=='0')   
     $('td:eq(6)').find('+.PrintReport').hide();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks :)
What's the usage of + in this line ?
     $('td:eq(6)').find('+.PrintReport').hide();

Comment: @sahin- including + in your selector will give you all the elementwith class .PrintReport in side sixth column,so you don't have to care about individula td..

Answer (score 2):

```
$('table tr').filter(function () {
    return $('td:eq(4) > span', this).text() == "0";
}).find('td:eq(6) > .PrintReport').hide();
```

**UPDATE**: If you're looking for the 4th and 6th column (in human measures) you have to use 3 and 5 respectively for `:eq`, because it works with 0-based indexes. I left my example as it was, just wanted to give this warning.

I also added a working demo:
[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/489R6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Gotta run but this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/aAQNC/4/
Loop through each row with .each...

```
 $("#table tr").each(function() {
      $(this).children("td:eq(6) > .PrintReport").hide();
      });
```

Comment: this does not check if the value of span is "0"

Comment: @Raja I figured OP is capable of adding that in himself :-) ...plus, it seemed the main question was how to work with all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use each() for it to work for every row. Please try this(just wrote it on the fly and not tested):

```
$('#table  tr  td:eq(4) > span').each(function(){
  if ($(this).html() == "0") {
            $(this).closest("tr").find('.PrintReport').hide();
        }
});
```

Comment: closet will only look for prevous rows of current rows.